# How to convert video to transcript locally on PC?

Tags: video-conversion, speech-to-text

I am seeking a certain feature. At my University, the professor is recording his lectures, and uploading the videos to his website. On the website, he has some kind of software which converts his spoken words into transcript in real time. He made it clear that he didn't write the transcript, rather the software analyzed the sound, and constructed the transcript from his spoken words.

[image]

This professor created his own custom website with this feature. Other professors only record their lectures and upload them to the University's cloud server, without any additional processing. Then I have to download their lectures from the server, and watch the videos locally on my PC. So the other professors don't use such software, and probably don't know how to set it up either.

I find that I learn much better when there is a transcript available, because English is my second language. Sometimes it is difficult to listen, particularly when people speak quickly and have non-standard (black African) accents. I have to rewind the video multiple times in order to understand what they are saying. Where as here I can just watch the video and if any spoken word is unclear, the transcript shows it, or if the transcript is wrong I can make an educated guess based on the context.

I download the lectures from the other professors from the University cloud server onto my PC. **I am seeking a software that can locally take input the video file (mp3) and generate a complete transcript**. This software should run locally on the PC only, it should not send the data to some server for processing. It should work on the PC only without an internet connection. It can be somewhat slow, like 10 minutes for a 30 minute lecture, but that is fine, since I am getting the transcript only once. And most importantly, it should be a free or open source software.

Comment: “This professor created his own custom website with this feature. Other professors only record their lectures and upload them to the University's cloud server, without any additional processing.” How do you know that the professor did this on his own? Seems like a heavy lift for him to do that. Can you ask him about all of this to see if he can share info on what tools he uses? Desktop transcription software definitely exists.

Comment: My professor responded to my request, and he uses Kaltura software.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop transcription software exists, but a lot of them are paid, and most of them require active internet connection. Even if you manage to find some software, IMO it won't be as accurate due to less datasets.

If I had to do it, I'd convert the original video to video with blank screen(this will reduce the size of the video substantially and speed up the process) using ffmpeg and upload it to youtube and let it auto transcribe and then download the subtitles.(Obviously I'd a program to automate all of it). But that would go against your local only processing.

Also, I own a Pixel Device and the transcription of it is really good and accurate and it works offline. You can probably use Android Emulator to achieve this. I just googled it and the recorder app can be used on non-pixel devices from certain manufacturers.

**Edit:**
For 1st method, you could use [Youtube's Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) to upload video and to get the subtitles file you could use [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/). I don't know how much time it would take for Youtube to process the video generate the subtitles. So you would have to experiment and find out.

Also One thing, make sure you upload the videos as private.

For 2nd method, convert the video to audio by ffmpeg(I don't use it often so I don't remember the exact input, but you can google it, there are  a lot of answers out there),and then maybe use adb to push that to the directory where Google Recorder saves its recording. And then manually open the Recorder app and export the transcript(you probably could automate it, but it would require a lot of time to set it up).I'm not sure if this will work, because maybe the transcription takes place during recording.

Comment: Interesting. Please provide more information. About ffmpeg and program to automate it. Can you automatically upload and download to/from Youtube? Can you use C++ to do it? And also about Android Emulator.

Comment: @Galaxy Updated the answer. I'm not familiar with C++ but Python is simple enough.

Comment: -1 While well intentioned, this answer is really an extended brainstorming comment. The original poster clearly wants a tutorial on how to do this and this site is not about tutorials. The reality is many off-the-shelf transcription software packages are out there. Your request is not unusual. I still recommend what I mentioned in my initial comment: Ask that professor what they use. That is the best thing you can do to help you help yourself in doing this.

Comment: +1 Because I found this information useful too. These are some good suggestions, from both of you.